# Responsive menu with hamburger icon aligned to the left

Tags: html, css

I have a responsive menu that on large screens you see the drop-down menu centered on the page. But on small screens you see a hamburger menu also centered on the page, and I want the icon to be seen on the left. How can i do that? It looks like this: https://postimg.cc/dLFkHH1Z
On large screens there is no problem but in small screens i want to see the hamburguer icon on the left.
Thanks in advance.

```js
/* Toggle between adding and removing the "responsive" class to topnav when the user clicks on the icon */
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
```

```css
 /* Add a black background color to the top navigation */

.topnav {
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

/* Add an active class to highlight the current page */
.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

/* Hide the link that should open and close the topnav on small screens */
.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

/* Dropdown container - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* Style the dropdown button to fit inside the topnav */
.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 17px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

/* Style the dropdown content (hidden by default) */
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

/* Style the links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

/* Add a dark background on topnav links and the dropdown button on hover */
.topnav a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}

/* Add a grey background to dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

/* Show the dropdown menu when the user moves the mouse over the dropdown button */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

/* When the screen is less than 600 pixels wide, hide all links, except for the first one ("Home"). Show the link that contains should open and close the topnav (.icon) */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a, .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

/* The "responsive" class is added to the topnav with JavaScript when the user clicks on the icon. This class makes the topnav look good on small screens (display the links vertically instead of horizontally) */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive a.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown {float: none;}
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>Menú Desplegable Responsive</title>
    <LINK REL=StyleSheet HREF="estilos.css" TYPE="text/css">
    <script src="menu.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
</div>     
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Make your code runnable in a stack-snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found the solution.

```js
document.getElementById("menuBars").onclick = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  x.classList.toggle("responsive");
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

/*
.topnav .fl {
  float: left;
}

.topnav .fr {
  float: right;
}
*/
.topnav .main {
  display: inline-block;
}

.topnav .main a {
  float: left;
}

.topnav a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

main {
  padding-left: 16px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .topnav a, .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {
    position: relative;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Menú</title>
          <LINK REL=StyleSheet HREF="estilos.css" TYPE="text/css">
        <script src="menu.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#about" >About</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <!--<a href="" class="icon" id="menuBars">-->
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="menuBars" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
</nav>
  
</body>
</html>
```